# Visiblox invalid assembly reference

Tags: c#, wpf, assemblies, visiblox

I am struggling with a problem regarding to [visiblox](http://visiblox.com). I am quite new to the WPF concept, but I am getting the hang of it. I have quite some expirence with the classic forms.

My problem is that the designer keeps telling me that the XAML contains errors. And I get the folling error in my error list:

```
Unable to load the metadata for assembly 'Visiblox.Charts'. 
This assembly may have been downloaded from the web.
See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=179545.
The following error was encountered during load: Could not load file or assembly     
'Visiblox.Charts, Version=2.1.4.31043, Culture=neutral, publicKeyToken=1543c03f04c4461b' or one of its dependencies.
```

I have added the reference to the project, and I have added the line:

`xmlns:charts="clr-namespace:Visiblox.Charts;assembly=Visiblox.Charts"`

I can build and run the project, but the designer keeps telling me that my assemblies are not correct. I tried to clean and rebuilt the project. Restarted Visual Studio and the computer, but nothing seems to work. Anyone any clue? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest following the link it provides: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=179545

The problem is that the dll is "locked" by windows security and you need to unlock it before you can reference it.  The link specified tells you how.